# SQL MIN() & GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, min

I'm searching for a more elegant solution to a problem I'm having with MySQL MIN() used in conjunction with GROUP BY.

I have two tables:

1. products (id, group_id)
2. product_attributes (product_id, attribute_id, value)

I wish to select the cheapest metal out of each metal group (attribute_id = 40) from a certain product group.

The following query works but I'm quite certain it could have been written much better.

```
SELECT metal.product_id, metal.value AS `metal`, `price`.value AS `price`
FROM
    product_attributes metal
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT metal.value AS `metal`, MIN(price.value) AS `price`
        FROM 
            product_attributes metal
        LEFT JOIN 
            product_attributes price
        ON metal.product_id = price.product_id
        INNER JOIN products p
        ON p.id = metal.product_id
        WHERE
            metal.attribute_id = 40 AND
            price.attribute_id = 37 AND
            p.group_id = 1
        GROUP BY
            metal.value
        ORDER BY metal ASC, price DESC
    ) AS d ON
    d.metal = metal.value
LEFT JOIN
    product_attributes price ON
    metal.product_id = price.product_id AND price.attribute_id = 37
INNER JOIN
    products p ON
    p.id = metal.product_id
WHERE
    metal.attribute_id = 40
    AND d.price = price.value
    AND p.group_id = 1
GROUP BY
    metal.value
ORDER BY
    metal.value ASC,
    price.value DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution finally was simpler than I though.
I've ordered my data by price in an inner query, thus forcing a sort before GROUP BY, this way I get exactly what I need (the cheapest product from each metal group).

```
SELECT * FROM
            (
                SELECT metal.enum_id AS `metal`, metal.product_id FROM product_attributes metal
                LEFT JOIN product_attributes price ON metal.product_id = price.product_id AND price.attribute_id = 37
                INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = metal.product_id
                WHERE
                    metal.attribute_id = 40 AND
                    p.group_id = 1 AND
                    p.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM product_attributes WHERE (attribute_id=162 OR attribute_id=204 OR attribute_id=205) AND `value`=1)
                ORDER BY price.value+'0' ASC 
            ) AS s
            GROUP BY metal
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just write this as a `group by` statement:

```
  SELECT metal.value AS `metal`, metal.product_id, MIN(price.value) AS `price`
  FROM product_attributes metal LEFT JOIN 
       product_attributes price
       ON metal.product_id = price.product_id
       INNER JOIN products p
       ON p.id = metal.product_id
  WHERE metal.attribute_id = 40 AND
        price.attribute_id = 37 AND
        p.group_id = 1
  GROUP BY metal
  order by metal, price
```

This works, assuming that there is one `product_id` per `metal.value`.  If there are multiple such product ids, then you need to join back in the attributes table:

```
SELECT metal.product_id, metal.value AS `metal`, d.`price`
FROM (SELECT metal.value AS `metal`, MIN(price.value) AS `price`
      FROM product_attributes metal LEFT JOIN 
           product_attributes price
           ON metal.product_id = price.product_id
           INNER JOIN products p
           ON p.id = metal.product_id
      WHERE metal.attribute_id = 40 AND
            price.attribute_id = 37 AND
            p.group_id = 1
      GROUP BY metal
    ) d join
    product_attributes metal
    ON d.metal = metal.value
ORDER BY metal.value ASC, d.price DESC
```

It is possible that you also might need the `where` and additional joins.  That depends on the structure of your data.