# i want to get lowest price values with id in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

my query is

```
SELECT productscrapeddatalog.*, product.productname 
FROM productscrapeddatalog JOIN product
  ON productscrapeddatalog.productID = product.productID 
WHERE price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM productscrapeddatalog ORDER BY productID)
```

this is my table screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ?

Comment: If I understand, you want the lowest price's row for each distinct `productID` ?

Comment: yes , you understand right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL MIN() & GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003663/sql-min-group-by)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. Put everything needed in your post not just at a link. [ask] [help]

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach with a join and filtering in the `where` clause is ok - but you need to *correlate* the subquery with the outer query so you get the lowest price *per product* rathern thatn the overall min:

```
SELECT l.*, p.productname 
FROM productscrapeddatalog l
JOIN product p ON l.productID = l.productID 
WHERE l.price = (
    SELECT MIN(l1.price) 
    FROM productscrapeddatalog l1
    WHERE l1.productID = t.productID
)
```

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can also do this with window functions:

```
SELECT l.*, p.productname 
FROM product p
JOIN (
    SELECT l.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY productID ORDER BY price) rn 
    FROM productscrapeddatalog l
) p ON l.productID = l.productID AND l.rn = 1
```

Comment: this will give me whole table

Comment: @BalrajSingh: no, the correlation handles the filtering. Plese tryn the query by yourself, and see what it returns.

Comment: im checking , this will give me whole table

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
SELECT productscrapeddatalog.*, product.productname, MIN(productscrapeddatalog.price) 
FROM productscrapeddatalog JOIN product
  ON productscrapeddatalog.productID = product.productID 
ORDER BY productID
```

Comment: no this give me only result for 1, but  i want 2 , 3 with this